# Translate string in another langage than Locale

Tags: php, plugin-development, translation

I am developping a plugin for my company to register projects with some products. I am creating a purchase order for my supplier with this products.

My local langage is french but my supplier is german. All my texts are ready for translatation like this :  `__("Total height","wp_gestion")`

Translation are working fine in my local language. Now I would like to create the purchase order in German. Do you have any idea how to use my german translation despite my local langage is rench ?

Thanks for your help